# ACS712 active and reactive current

Tags: current, current-measurement, high-voltage

I am planning to use ACS712 5A current sensor in my project an I was wondering if anyone knows if this sensor measures just the Active Current or also the Reactive Current.

The datasheet doesn't say anything particular, and I wonder if that may or may not affect the calculations. The controller input pins are connected to the 220V output right after the 220V transformers and a DL-1D31 filter.

Answer (score 1):

> *I was wondering if anyone knows if this sensor measures just the
> Active Current or also the Reactive Current*

It measure the "apparent" (or total) current flowing through it. "Apparent" current is the quadrature total of "active" and "reactive" currents. There is no way a device like this has the ability to distinguish between "active" and "reactive" currents.

I'm using the terms in inverted commas because, in reality they mean this: -

- "Apparent" is the current associated with the apparent power of the load
- "Active" is the current associated with the active power of the load
- "Reactive" is the current associated with the reactive power of load

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2013/07/active-reactive-apparent-and-complex.html).

Answer (score 1):

The ACS712 has a Hall sensor that outputs a voltage proportional to the instantaneous current, over a reasonable bandwidth (they quote  typical risetime of 5us. It doesn't 'measure' anything. How you measure that voltage is up to you.

If you simply measure the magnitude, either as the mean rectified (what older DMMs do), or the true RMS AC (what some newer DMMs do) of that voltage, then you'll read the quadrature sum of the active and reactive components.

If you demodulate the signal with respect to the voltage on the circuit you're measuring, then you can resolve the active and reactive currents. You may be able to find software that turns the audio input of a PC sound card into a suitable demodulator, or you could write your own.